# Search implementation through web service?

Tags: android, performance, search

Please share some suggestions to implement search options by `Edittext or (AutoCompleteTextView)`. It doesn't matter what widget we are gonna use. While entering any text into the `Widget(EditText or AutoCompleteTextview)`, The related search results should be fetched from server through web service and these contents should be viewed in listview (By Influencing `notifyDataSetChanged()` in adapter after every search results). What is the efficient method to achieve this?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your case [ThresholdEditText](https://code.google.com/p/android-threshold-edittext/) will help to achieve.

Using `searchBox.setThreshold(2000);` its wait till user enter the text within given time and also set `setOnThresholdTextChanged` to do action after user enter the text within `Editbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [debounce](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure#debounce-or-throttlewithtimeout) function with RxJava Android.